# why can't I use IP address of locally running mongod server to add it to mongodb replication set

Tags: mongodb

I am having 3 mongod servers running locally on different ports as with below command

```
mongod.exe --port 27017 --replSet rs0 --dbpath C:\data\db1 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128

mongod.exe --port 27018 --replSet rs0 --dbpath C:\data\db2 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128

mongod.exe --port 27019 --replSet rs0 --dbpath C:\data\db3 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

this will start three mongoDB server locally.

Now to to configure the replication set I used the following commands

```
rsconf = { _id : rs0,
           members: [
                      {_id:1, host:"localhost:27017"}
                    ]
         }
```

then to start

```
rs.initiate(rsconfig)
```

now to add other members

```
rs.add({_id:2, host: "localhost:27018"})
```

works fine however the following

```
rs.add({_id:2, host: "10.212.71.116"})
```

throws an exception -

```
   {
        "errmsg" : "exception: can't use localhost in repl set member names exce
pt when using it for all members",
        "code" : 13393,
        "ok" : 0
}
```

I am newbie to mongoDB hence it seems more proper for me to use IP address(for localhost) than localhost. Why is this so in mongoDB?

Comment: After searching a lot I just came to know that the mongoDB documentation specifies that the localhost and non-localhost members can't be mixed. And that errormsg itself says that if you are using localhost in specifying members then for that replica set all the members should be localhost only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while going through documentation for mongodb sharding I found following statement

Because all components of a sharded cluster must communicate with each other over the network, there are special restrictions regarding the use of localhost addresses:

If you use either “localhost” or “127.0.0.1” as the host identifier, then you must use “localhost” or “127.0.0.1” for all host settings for any MongoDB instances in the cluster. This applies to both the host argument to addShard and the value to the mongos --configdb run time option. If you mix localhost addresses with remote host address, MongoDB will produce errors.

on page "http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures/#sharding-requirements-infrastructure"

This implies that when you are in test environment and do not want to add hosts other than localhost then you can go with the approach of using localhost, otherwise prefer using IP address

Comment: Makes sense, but you are referring to the documentation for sharded clusters. The question is about replica sets (the rules are probably the same, but this is guess work).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After `rs.initiate()` look at the me field in printed result of this command. It's the name of your computer. For me it was `Apollo-17:27001` . Having this information add other 2 servers: >`rs.add("Apollo-17:27002")` etc. Ensure that everything is ok: in console you will see `{ "ok" : 1 }` . That's all.