# Couldn't connect to new shard ReplicaSetMonitor no master found for set

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to deploy sharded cluster in Mongodb

I followed up the tutorial here

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/

first I deployed a Replica set with test data on a separate machine with IP 192.168.1.212

and this is the status after I finished deploying it

```
firstset:PRIMARY> rs.status();
{
    "set" : "firstset",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-03-24T10:54:06Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "localhost:10001",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 117,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1395650164, 10507),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-03-24T08:36:04Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "localhost:10002",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 65,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1395650164, 10507),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-03-24T08:36:04Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-03-24T10:54:05Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-03-24T10:54:05Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "syncing to: localhost:10001",
            "syncingTo" : "localhost:10001"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "localhost:10003",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 51,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1395650164, 10507),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-03-24T08:36:04Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-03-24T10:54:05Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-03-24T10:54:04Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "syncing to: localhost:10001",
            "syncingTo" : "localhost:10001"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Then I deployed three config server on separate machine then run mongos instance on another machine

Then I wanted to add Replica shard using the following command

```
sh.addShard("firstset/192.168.1.212:10001,192.168.1.212:10002,192.168.1.212:10003")
```

But I get the following error

```
mongos> sh.addShard('firstset/192.168.1.212:10001,192.168.1.212:10002,192.168.1.212:10003');
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "couldn't connect to new shard ReplicaSetMonitor no master found for set: firstset"
}
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038051/why-cant-i-use-ip-address-of-locally-running-mongod-server-to-add-it-to-mongodb

Comment: Np glad to hve helped I remember having the same problem but I couldn't remember exactly the cause of it, that answer sums it up well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem with Sammaye's help

the problem was that when replica set is initiated you should take care of the IPs you use because when the router will try to connect to the replica set, it reads its configuration file
So if you use `rs.initiate()` with setting your configuration, the configuration will be like that

```
{
    "_id" : "firstset",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "localhost:10001"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "localhost:10002"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "host" : "localhost:10003"
        }
    ]
}
```

So the router will try to search at localhost to find the primary replica set but it won't find it because it is on other machine

If you use different machines for testing so initialize Replica set manually as following

```
rsconf ={
    "_id" : "firstset",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "machine_ip:machine_port"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "machine_ip:machine_port"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "host" : "machine_ip:machine_port"
        }
    ]
}
rs.initiate(rsconf);
```

Also if you use either “localhost” or “127.0.0.1” as the host identifier, then you must use “localhost” or “127.0.0.1” for all host settings for any MongoDB instances in the cluster. This applies to both the host argument to addShard and the value to the mongos --configdb run time option. If you mix localhost addresses with remote host address, MongoDB will produce errors.