# how to replicate mongodb multiple instance on same host

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am running 3 MongoDB instance on local machine and also trying to create its replica set.

```
mongod.exe --port 2021 --dbpath C:\mongodb\data --replSet rs0

mongod.exe --port 2022 --dbpath D:\mongodb\data --replSet rs0

mongod.exe --port 2023 --dbpath E:\mongodb\data --replSet rs0
```

after this i am running the mongo command for port 2021 like

```
mongo.exe --port 2021
```

then i am using these command like

```
rs.initiate()
rs.add("127.0.0.1:2022");
```

But it is not adding these instance for replica set and returns me the error

```
errmsg" : "exception: can't use localhost in repl set member names except when using it for all members",
```

I just want to know can i not add mongodb instance on 127.0.0.1  with different port for the replica.

I am new to mongodb and stuck in solving these issues.

Comment: Sounds like you are mixing localhosts and non-localhost addresses. See the answer to this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038051/why-cant-i-use-ip-address-of-locally-running-mongod-server-to-add-it-to-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before and agree with thelok's suggestion. After you've read the other answer he linked to, check your rs after immediately you execute the rs.initiate() and before you try to add the second member. How is the primary member referred to? Is it by the host name, the FQDN, or another ip address other than local (127.0.0.1)?

Use that same name when executing rs.add(:).

That's how it worked for me.